# Why NOT NULL data constraint defined with Laravel's schema builder allows NULL value being inserted when using SQLite3?

Tags: sqlite, laravel, database-schema

I am trying to not save eloquent database models which have `null` values. I have this in my migration file:

```php
$table->increments('id')->unique();
$table->string('name', 255)->unique();
$table->string('email', 255)->unique();
$table->string('password', 64);
$table->timestamps();
```

The Schema documentation says that the default value is `NOT NULL`, but with `->nullable()` you can allow null values, cool! So my `User` model set email method looks like:

```php
public function setEmailAttribute( $value ) 
{
    if ( filter_var( $value, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL ) ) 
    {
        $this->attributes['email'] = strtolower( $value );
    } 
    else 
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

But now in my TestClass he saves the model without setting an email adress!?!

```php
$userSave3 = new User;
$userSave3->setNameAttribute('wrongUser');
$this->assertEquals( false, $userSave3->setEmailAttribute('wrongemail') );
$userSave3->setPasswordAttribute('password');
// Failed asserting that true matches expected false.
$this->assertEquals( false, $userSave3->save() );
```

So how can I add `NOT NULL` data constraints? I am using SQLite in development mode.

Comment: I have see this behavior too. It only seems to occur with SQLite...

Comment: It seems that is not possible using Laravel's schema builder. I filed an issue explaining the problem: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/2120

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taylor Otwell, recently said that **this bug has been fixed**. In the past I had filed an issue on Github, and now you can see the answer from Otwell:

> I believe this has been fixed.

https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/2120#issuecomment-25551048

Comment: Is this really an answer?

Comment: @briankip yes, it is. This was a bug in the framework BUT the answer should provide valid data to back it up here other than a comment of a comment.